# How can FileOpenPicker pick file without extension?

Tags: c#, uwp

## The picker requires specific file type, and the pickerUI  just display those type file:

```
        FileOpenPicker fileOpenPicker = new FileOpenPicker();

        fileOpenPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");
```

## But now I have two stages to use the FileOpenPicker in different ways:

1. View the file without  extension , and pick it
2. View all files , not only the required files, and pick it

### I tried these code :

```
        fileOpenPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("");

        fileOpenPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".");

        fileOpenPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".*");
```

It doesn't work

## How can I do that?

Comment: The example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker.filetypefilter?view=winrt-22621) shows adding just a wildcard, which is probably to specify all files.

Comment: If you're saying that you want to display just the files with no extension then I'm guessing that that is impossible. There's no simple filter string that would match a file name with no extension that wouldn't also match a file name with an extension. If you were doing it yourself then you could use regular expressions but I very much doubt that that is available in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use the following code:

```
fileOpenPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
```

This will not set the file type when you use the file picker